# write existing xfce4 configurations to disk

Tags: xfce

I accidentally deleted everything in `~/.config/xfce4` in the process of backing it up (yeah, laugh it up). Simple question, is there a way to have xfce write all configurations currently in memory back to disk?

Comment: If your Kernel ist compilled with `cat /boot/config-$(uname -r) | grep -i devmem
CONFIG_STRICT_DEVMEM=y`  I think you have bad luck.  [link] (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KLI46yMdtmU) ^^. s.c.n.r.